# Why does the following not compile when trying to connect to Postgres in Rust

Tags: postgresql, rust

When trying to connect to Postgres the following line works as in the docs

```
let conn = PostgresConnection::connect("postgres://postgres@localhost",
                                       &NoSsl).unwrap();
```

But once I change that to this:

```
let conn = try!(PostgresConnection::connect("postgres://postgres@localhost", &NoSsl));
```

I get the following compile error:

```
<std macros>:2:59: 2:65 error: mismatched types: expected `()` but found `core::result::Result<<generic #16>,postgres::error::PostgresConnectError>` (expected () but found enum core::result::Result)
<std macros>:2     ($e:expr) => (match $e { Ok(e) => e, Err(e) => return Err(e) })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try!()` macro transforms this code:

```
let conn = try!(PostgresConnection::connect("postgres://postgres@localhost", &NoSsl));
```

into this:

```
let conn = match PostgresConnection::connect("postgres://postgres@localhost", &NoSsl) {
    Ok(e) => e,
    Err(e) => return Err(e)
};
```

That is, in case of error it returns from the function it is invoked in. Hence, this function must return something of type `Result<..., PostgresConnectError>`. However, in your case it seems that the function you're calling this macro in does not return anything (that is, it returns unit `()`: `fn whatever() { }` - no return type).

`Result::unwrap()`, on the other hand, causes task failure if the result value is `Err`, and it is a function, so it doesn't depend on function return type.